# Convert polynomial of fractional order to polynomial of integer order

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, polynomials, linear-transformations, transformation

There is an equation:

$p(x) = (\alpha \cdot x + 1)^{3/2}$

Are there ways to convert this equation into a polynomial of integer order with an arbitrary highest degree (with even or odd choice), for example:

$p(x) = (\alpha \cdot x + 1)^{3/2} \xrightarrow{Transform} p(x) = c_0 + c_1 \cdot x^1+ ... + c_m \cdot x^m$

where $m$ - even or odd arbitrary degree of polynomial, and $c_i$ - polynomial coefficients.

***Here we are not talking about approximating this equation by polynomials and not about expanding it into a Taylor series.***

*In general, this is a bad way for this equation, because with an increase in the $\alpha$ coefficient, the Runge phenomenon manifests itself more and more.*

This is a fractional order system, the structure is very similar to the polynomial equation, so I thought that there should be ways to convert the fractional order system into a similar integer order system that describes the same curve on any interval as the original fractional order system.

Is there such a transformation?

***EDIT:***

I would like to specify the problem:

There is the following ratio:

$f(x) = \frac{(x+1)^4}{(\alpha \cdot x + 1)^{3/2}}$

It is necessary to eliminate the fractional degree from this ratio and at the same time observe the condition under which the order of the numerator should not exceed the order of the denominator.

I will try to show why squaring is not a very good solution in this case:

$f(x) = \frac{((x+1)^4)^2}{((\alpha \cdot x + 1)^{3/2})^2} = \frac{(x+1)^8}{(\alpha \cdot x + 1)^{3}}$

In this case, the degree of the numerator is greater than the order of the denominator.

***EDIT №2:***

Squaring helps only if the order of the denominator is greater than the order of the numerator from the very beginning. Therefore, my comment should not be taken as a complete rejection of this method.

It seems to me that there should be a more elegant way.

Comment: If you have a system like $y=(\alpha x+1)^{3/2}$, would rewriting is at $y^2=(\alpha x+1)^3$ do the trick? If not, I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: What kind of "transform" are you looking too?

Comment: @Carl Schildkraut - This option does not suit me. The reason is that the original fractional order system is involved in a number of algebraic relations. For example, I have a polynomial of degree 2 included in the numerator, and the original polynomial of polynomial order included in the denominator. If I square this ratio, then in the denominator I get a power of 3, and in the numerator a power of 4. The order of the numerator should not exceed the order of the denominator.

Comment: @Carl Schildkraut - It is necessary to artificially increase the degree of the denominator, while eliminating this fractional degree. Thus, the method proposed by you will not succeed.

Comment: @LL - A transformation that turns a fractional order polynomial into an integer order polynomial that preserves the properties of the original one (at least having the same graph). I am not a specialist in mathematics, so I do not know if such a transformation exists. So I ask.

Comment: Do you look for a transform or just another way to write $p$? $p$ is for sure not a polynomial.

Comment: Perhaps I am a little incorrect in terminology. I am looking for a write of the original function $p(x)$ in the form of a polynomial.
P.S. Look at the original equation $p(x)$, doesn’t it look like a polynomial? The sum of the parameters with coefficients and a constant under the power. Constant 1 can be considered as an offset along the x axis.

Comment: Only even power as indicated by Carl then.

Comment: Please, see third comment.

Comment: You can square numerator and denominator if you want the order to be preserved. And unfortunately you have no other choice, even if you don't like it ... So is the world ^^

Comment: Please see my edit. I hope I haven’t made a mistake anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, if I understand your question correctly, there is no polynomial that suits your needs.

You are looking for some polynomial $P(x)$ so that
$$P(x)=(\alpha x+1)^{3/2}$$
for all real $x$. Squaring this, we must certainly have that
$$P(x)^2=(\alpha x+1)^3$$
for all $x$. However, now both sides are actually polynomials, so they must in fact be the same polynomial. However, the degree of the polynomial on the left side is $2\deg P$, while the degree of the right side is $3$ (unless $\alpha=0$). Since $3$ is not even, $2\deg P\neq 3$, and thus we have reached a contradiction.

If you are satisfied with an approximation on an interval, take a look at the [Stone--Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem). It tells you that, given any continuous function on any interval, you can always approximate it as well as you desire by a polynomial.

Comment: I know this theorem. I use it in some cases. Nevertheless, to fight with the Runge phenomenon, an extremely high polynomial order is needed and the choice of the correct interpolation points is necessary. The high order of the polynomial is redundant, and even Mathematica is not always good at choosing interpolation points.

Comment: @dtn The Runge phenomenon is why simple polynomial interpolation is not the way to go. Least squares should work better.